# Seprate values on basis of '\n'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pdf file and extracting the data from pdf file using pdfquery and pandas

Code is as follows:

```
 import pdfquery
 import pandas as pd
 pdf = pdfquery.PDFQuery('data/BUSTA_PAGA - 2.pdf')
 pdf.load()
 pdf.tree.write('pdfXML.txt', pretty_print = True)

 Name = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("25.509, 188.273, 188.558, 
 748.621")').text()
 s=pd.DataFrame({
 Name
 })
 s.to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

When I run this, It gives the data of the full text box which I wanted but there is specific data that I want to extract. How would I do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You wrote all that code, so why not take the next step and implement that feature. I'm a bit puzzled what your problem is, also how it relates to the title of your question. Also, make sure you read [ask] and took the [tour].